# How to visually edit the interface on android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, ide

I recently started programming on android and every time I have to write a xml for the interface, roughly speaking, I got sick of it. One time university we study a visual studio on this program, we could create interfece programm with drag in drop component. I want to know if there is there such a possibility, if you modify the interface, the program itself converted the interface to xml?

Comment: When you open your .xml file, You should have an options on the right side saying `Design`, `Code`. Toggle them, see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .xml on the top right corner, you can find `design` and `code` options, and if you want `drag and drop` feature you can choose `design` and you can add features by simply drag and drop. If you want any default template you can choose while creating a project or while creating new `activity`.